# TimerJobs and ULS

Tags: custom-timer-job, uls

I have developed a custom Timer Job, which is deployed to my Sharepoint 2010 Enterprise environment.

I often notice that things that happen in the TimerJob will not be entered into the ULS, in the same way it would be if the code was in an EventReceiver or elsewhere. I have logging set to Verbose for everything; but none of the areas seems to cover timer jobs.

This is particularly frustrating when in the process of development; as things like a connection to an external database being refused will just be ignored, with nothing to say what has gone wrong in any of the logs I can find.

So, my question: is there a way to have errors/exceptions in TimerJobs logged to the ULS?

Comment: Whats the reason for wanting to use the ULS logs to log the issue?

Comment: @Truezplaya because that's where all other logging for SharePoint goes, so having it there makes sense.

Comment: I was just wondering because whenever we've written timer jobs they always log to the application log, I never really thought about putting it to the ULS because there not the easiest logs to read!

Comment: @Truezplaya Yes, I agree that ULS isn't particularly friendly; but it's the only log that our organisations infrastructure will give us access to without a long process of politics.

Answer (score 3):

I have been developing timer job for quiet a while now and always created myself a Event log specially for timer job to log when it started or stopped and also if there is any error came up while execution.

I use this code to write messages to event log you can also add code to send an email to a specific user in case of error if you would like to,

```
private string eventLogName;

public void WriteToLog(string logSource, string message)
{
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
    {
        if (!EventLog.Exists(eventLogName))
        {
            EventLog eventLog = new EventLog(eventLogName);
        }

        if (!EventLog.SourceExists(logSource))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource(logSource, eventLogName);
        }

        EventLog.WriteEntry(logSource, message, EventLogEntryType.Error);

    });
}
```

ULS logs have errors, information and so many other messages so my personal opinion is to avoid it, however if you still insist then here's the code for that,

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;

namespace ManagedTraceProvider
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TraceProvider.RegisterTraceProvider();

        TraceProvider.WriteTrace(0, TraceProvider.TraceSeverity.High, Guid.Empty, "MyExeName", "Product Name", "Category Name", "Sample Message");
        TraceProvider.WriteTrace(TraceProvider.TagFromString("abcd"), TraceProvider.TraceSeverity.Monitorable, Guid.NewGuid(), "MyExeName", "Product Name", "Category Name", "Sample Message");

        TraceProvider.UnregisterTraceProvider();
    }
}

static class TraceProvider
{
    static UInt64 hTraceLog;
    static UInt64 hTraceReg;

    static class NativeMethods
    {
        internal const int TRACE_VERSION_CURRENT = 1;
        internal const int ERROR_SUCCESS = 0;
        internal const int ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER = 87;
        internal const int WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID = 0x00020000;

        internal enum TraceFlags
        {
            TRACE_FLAG_START = 1,
            TRACE_FLAG_END = 2,
            TRACE_FLAG_MIDDLE = 3,
            TRACE_FLAG_ID_AS_ASCII = 4
        }

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct EVENT_TRACE_HEADER_CLASS
        {
            internal byte Type;
            internal byte Level;
            internal ushort Version;
        }

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct EVENT_TRACE_HEADER
        {
            internal ushort Size;
            internal ushort FieldTypeFlags;
            internal EVENT_TRACE_HEADER_CLASS Class;
            internal uint ThreadId;
            internal uint ProcessId;
            internal Int64 TimeStamp;
            internal Guid Guid;
            internal uint ClientContext;
            internal uint Flags;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal struct ULSTraceHeader
        {
            internal ushort Size;
            internal uint dwVersion;
            internal uint Id;
            internal Guid correlationID;
            internal TraceFlags dwFlags;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            internal string wzExeName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            internal string wzProduct;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 32)]
            internal string wzCategory;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 800)]
            internal string wzMessage;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        internal struct ULSTrace
        {
            internal EVENT_TRACE_HEADER Header;
            internal ULSTraceHeader ULSHeader;
        }

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        internal enum WMIDPREQUESTCODE
        {
            WMI_GET_ALL_DATA = 0,
            WMI_GET_SINGLE_INSTANCE = 1,
            WMI_SET_SINGLE_INSTANCE = 2,
            WMI_SET_SINGLE_ITEM = 3,
            WMI_ENABLE_EVENTS = 4,
            WMI_DISABLE_EVENTS = 5,
            WMI_ENABLE_COLLECTION = 6,
            WMI_DISABLE_COLLECTION = 7,
            WMI_REGINFO = 8,
            WMI_EXECUTE_METHOD = 9
        }

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        internal unsafe delegate uint EtwProc(NativeMethods.WMIDPREQUESTCODE requestCode, IntPtr requestContext, uint* bufferSize, IntPtr buffer);

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern unsafe uint RegisterTraceGuids([In] EtwProc cbFunc, [In] void* context, [In] ref Guid controlGuid, [In] uint guidCount, IntPtr guidReg, [In] string mofImagePath, [In] string mofResourceName, out ulong regHandle);

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern uint UnregisterTraceGuids([In]ulong regHandle);

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        internal static extern UInt64 GetTraceLoggerHandle([In]IntPtr Buffer);

        // Copied from Win32 APIs
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern uint TraceEvent([In]UInt64 traceHandle, [In]ref ULSTrace evnt);
    }

    public enum TraceSeverity
    {
        Unassigned = 0,
        CriticalEvent = 1,
        WarningEvent = 2,
        InformationEvent = 3,
        Exception = 4,
        Assert = 7,
        Unexpected = 10,
        Monitorable = 15,
        High = 20,
        Medium = 50,
        Verbose = 100,
    }

    public static void WriteTrace(uint tag, TraceSeverity level, Guid correlationGuid, string exeName, string productName, string categoryName, string message)
    {
        const ushort sizeOfWCHAR = 2;
        NativeMethods.ULSTrace ulsTrace = new NativeMethods.ULSTrace();

        // Pretty standard code needed to make things work
        ulsTrace.Header.Size = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.ULSTrace));
        ulsTrace.Header.Flags = NativeMethods.WNODE_FLAG_TRACED_GUID;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.dwVersion = NativeMethods.TRACE_VERSION_CURRENT;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.dwFlags = NativeMethods.TraceFlags.TRACE_FLAG_ID_AS_ASCII;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.Size = (ushort)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(NativeMethods.ULSTraceHeader));

        // Variables communicated to SPTrace
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.Id = tag;
        ulsTrace.Header.Class.Level = (byte)level;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.wzExeName = exeName;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.wzProduct = productName;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.wzCategory = categoryName;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.wzMessage = message;
        ulsTrace.ULSHeader.correlationID = correlationGuid;

        // Pptionally, to improve performance by reducing the amount of data copied around,
        // the Size parameters can be reduced by the amount of unused buffer in the Message
        if (message.Length < 800)
        {
            ushort unusedBuffer = (ushort) ((800 - (message.Length + 1)) * sizeOfWCHAR);
            ulsTrace.Header.Size -= unusedBuffer;
            ulsTrace.ULSHeader.Size -= unusedBuffer;
        }

        if (hTraceLog != 0)
            NativeMethods.TraceEvent(hTraceLog, ref ulsTrace);
    }

    public static unsafe void RegisterTraceProvider()
    {
        SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
        Guid traceGuid = farm.TraceSessionGuid;
        uint result = NativeMethods.RegisterTraceGuids(ControlCallback, null, ref traceGuid, 0, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, out hTraceReg);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(result == NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }

    public static void UnregisterTraceProvider()
    {
        uint result = NativeMethods.UnregisterTraceGuids(hTraceReg);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(result == NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS);
    }

    public static uint TagFromString(string wzTag)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(wzTag.Length == 4);
        return (uint) (wzTag[0] << 24 | wzTag[1] << 16 | wzTag[2] << 8 | wzTag[3]);
    }

    static unsafe uint ControlCallback(NativeMethods.WMIDPREQUESTCODE RequestCode, IntPtr Context, uint* InOutBufferSize, IntPtr Buffer)
    {
        uint Status;
        switch (RequestCode)
        {
            case NativeMethods.WMIDPREQUESTCODE.WMI_ENABLE_EVENTS:
                hTraceLog = NativeMethods.GetTraceLoggerHandle(Buffer);
                Status = NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS;
                break;
            case NativeMethods.WMIDPREQUESTCODE.WMI_DISABLE_EVENTS:
                hTraceLog = 0;
                Status = NativeMethods.ERROR_SUCCESS;
                break;
            default:
                Status = NativeMethods.ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
                break;
        }

        *InOutBufferSize = 0;
        return Status;
    }
}
}
```

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136672/programmatically-logging-to-the-sharepoint-uls