# What is good practice to log information in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, best-practices, logging, uls

We are creating a timer job that imports AD users into SharePoint list. I would liek to log this information somewhere so that at a later time I can check which users were pulled in and/why the program failed.

For this I have 3 options:-

1. ULS Log.
2. Write to C:\filename.txt
3. Write to event viewer.

Please guide as to which should be the approach on production server. Or if there is a better approach other than this?

Comment: Event viewer is a good option as well(at least for critical errors), since you can make easy to access categories for your code specifically.

Comment: I feel it is easier to code for logging into event viewer, and I dont feel it will cause burden on the system as logs are small files and text entries

Answer (score 3):

You can order up your approaches as below,

1. ULS
2. Event Viewer
3. Text file.

I suggest, **ULS** - Its the SharePoint native logging and it manages to remove the older files periodically, its better to keep all the SharePoint related logs in one place "ULS". Use `SPDiagnosticsService.Local.WriteTrace` [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spdiagnosticsservicebase.writetrace.aspx) in your timer job to log into the ULS logs

If you find that reading logs from ULS is difficult then you can end up with your own text file for logging the errors/messages.

Have a look at the below link too,

[TimerJobs and ULS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/55381/timerjobs-and-uls)

[Five suggestions to implement a better logging in SharePoint](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620996/Five-suggestions-to-implement-a-better-logging-in)